# Streaming iTunes Library from Raspberry Pi to AppleTV

Tags: streaming-video, media-server

I'm looking to replace an old computer with my Raspberry Pi. The computer is running Windows 7 and iTunes so that I can share my media library and at the same time stream movies, videos, and music to my AppleTV.

I don't think there exists a version of iTunes for Raspbian or Debian.

**Basically all I want to achieve is streaming movies/videos from my Raspberry Pi to my AppleTV.**

Has anyone done this with their Raspberry and how?

Comment: 10,000 views and not a single up vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Airplayer](https://github.com/gh0st/airplayer) worked phenomenally. Very lightweight, all I needed to do is ssh into my Pi, and run a shell command.

Comment: How did you manage to install Airplayer on raspberry pi? I tried to run the command lines from Airplayer home page but with no luck, it gives me an error.

Comment: What's the error?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a very early release and may not work/may not work well. That being said, articles from [redmondpie.com](http://www.redmondpie.com/how-to-sideload-install-kodi-on-apple-tv-4/), and [idownloadblog.com](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2015/12/24/how-install-kodi-new-apple-tv-4/) outline a method for sideloading Kodi onto an AppleTV. With Kodi installed you can use [samba](http://raspberrywebserver.com/serveradmin/share-your-raspberry-pis-files-and-folders-across-a-network.html) or similar to share content from your Pi to Kodi on the AppleTV. You are, apparently, going to need a Mac running XCode 7 and a USB C to USB A cable.

As posted on [idownloadblog.com](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2015/12/24/how-install-kodi-new-apple-tv-4/):

> Step 1: Download the latest nightly Kodi.deb file, the iOS App Signer,
>   (save both to desktop and unzip the iOS App Signer) and make sure you
>   have Xcode 7 installed.
>
> Step 2: Connect your Apple TV to your Mac using a USB Type-C cable.
>
> Step 3: Launch Xcode → click Create a new Xcode Project → select
>   Application under tvOS → Single View Application, and click Next.
>
> Step 4: In the Product name field, insert a unique name like
>   KodiAppleTVforYourNameHere and click Next → Create
>
> Step 5: Under the Team drop down box, select your personal team, and
>   click the Fix Issue button to resolve provisioning issues. You will
>   need to ensure that you are signed into Xcode with a free Apple
>   developer account. You can learn how to do that using this tutorial.
>
> Step 6: Ensure that your Apple TV is selected in the destination menu
>   at the top of the screen. You can also click Product → Destination,
>   and select Apple TV.
>
> Step 7: Minimize Xcode and open the iOS App Signer.
>
> Step 8: Click Browse on the iOS App Signer and select the Kodi.deb
>   nightly file from the desktop.
>
> Step 9: Select your Apple ID in the iOS App Signer’s Signing
>   Certificate box.
>
> Step 10: Select the Project name/bundle identifier you just created in
>   Xcode in iOS App Signer’s Provisioning Profile box.
>
> Step 11: Click Start in the bottom right-hand corner of the iOS App
>   Signer, and the .IPA file for Kodi will be built and saved to the
>   desktop.
>
> Step 12: Open Xcode → Window → Devices and select the Apple TV
>
> Step 13: Click the ‘+’ sign and select the .IPA file from the desktop
>   and click Open. Kodi will now be deployed to your Apple TV
>
> Step 14: Once finished, you should see the Kodi app on your Apple TV’s
>   Home screen.

Answer (score 0):

there is also a operating system called OSMC which stands for open source media center that currently supports both the pi and apple TV that you can download here https://osmc.tv/download/

Comment: This looks like it'd be the answer but after reading a little bit about it, it looks like I need to install a whole other OS besides Raspian, install Kodi on my AppleTV and then I'll finally be able to watch movies that I have saved to a hard drive plugged into my Pi. And that sounds like a heavy task. I was hoping that something existed for me to run alongside what's already running on the Pi. Not completely devote it to streaming videos.